How can I make Start Menu tile system in UWP app
I want to make a Windows 10-Like Tile system for my UWP app.
Here is the example:
Tile System.
I want to have groups (Like the "Code" group in the start menu),
and Tiles with image and text (Like the "Terminal" tile in the start menu)
I think the tiles are button with centered images and text, but how can I do the groups, and how can I automatically do the tile, do add them in C#.
I tried to make a TreeView, but it isn't what I really except.

look into uniform girds

It is recommeded to use UniformGrid. you can create a custom button which has both image and text content.
This is a simple example, using a custom button(public class RoundButton : Button), of course you can also customize the controls you want.
MainPage.xaml
<Page
    x:Class="UniformGridTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UniformGridTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="local:RoundButton">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:RoundButton">
                        <Border x:Name="border"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"          
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="border"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="border"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                            <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="border"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            
                            <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="9*"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Image x:Name="logoimage" Grid.Row="0" Source="{TemplateBinding IconImage}" Stretch="Uniform" />
                              
                                <ContentPresenter  Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentPresenter"   
                                                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"   
                                                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"  
                                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"  
                                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"  
                                                        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"  
                                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"   
                                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"   
                                                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"  
                                                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>

                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
      
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Width="800" Height="800">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="code" />
        <controls:UniformGrid Grid.Row="1" Rows="3" Columns="3" ColumnSpacing="10" RowSpacing="10">

            <local:RoundButton Content="Tile 1" IconImage="{Binding FirstImage}"  Height="200" Width="200"/>
            <local:RoundButton Content="Tile 2" IconImage="{Binding SecondImage}" Height="200" Width="200"/>
            <local:RoundButton Content="Tile 3" IconImage="{Binding ThirdImage}" Height="200" Width="200"/>

            <local:RoundButton Content="Tile 1" IconImage="{Binding FirstImage}"  Height="200" Width="200"/>
            <local:RoundButton Content="Tile 2" IconImage="{Binding SecondImage}" Height="200" Width="200"/>
            <local:RoundButton Content="Tile 3" IconImage="{Binding ThirdImage}" Height="200" Width="200"/>

         
        </controls:UniformGrid>



    </Grid>
</Page>

MainPage.xaml.cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainViewModel _viewModel = new MainViewModel();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = _viewModel;
    }

}

public class MainViewModel
{
    public BitmapImage FirstImage { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage SecondImage { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage ThirdImage { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        FirstImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/firstImg.png"));
        SecondImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/secondImg.png"));
        ThirdImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/thirdImg.png"));
    }
}


public class RoundButton : Button
 {
     public RoundButton()
     {
         this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(RoundButton);

     }

     public BitmapImage IconImage
     {
         get { return (BitmapImage)GetValue(IconImageProperty); }
         set { SetValue(IconImageProperty, value); }
     }

     // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IconImage.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...  
     public static readonly DependencyProperty IconImageProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("IconImage", typeof(BitmapImage), typeof(RoundButton), new PropertyMetadata(""));
 }

